# In the derivation of LSZ formula, why do we need $\langle k| \phi(0)|0 \rangle =1$? (Srednicki's book)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, operators, renormalization, s-matrix-theory

In the section 5 of the book, it says

> The LSZ formula is valid provided that the field obeys
> $$\langle 0|\phi(x)|0\rangle=0, \langle k|\phi(x)|0\rangle=1.$$

The second one is needed to ensure one-particle state is correctly normolized. But I cannot understand. My question is: in the derivation of LSZ formula, at which step do we use the condition?

I have also seen [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/525800/), but the 8th step confues me: $$\hat{a}^{\dagger}_1(\infty)- \hat{a}^{\dagger}_1(-\infty) 
=\sqrt{Z}[\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{1,{\rm out}}(\infty) - \hat{a}^{\dagger}_{1,{\rm in}}(-\infty)].$$

What are the $\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{1,{\rm out}}(\infty)$ and $\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{1,{\rm in}}(-\infty)$ here?