# I really wonder about the time derivative of creation and annihilation operators in the derivation of LSZ

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, operators, s-matrix-theory, asymptotics

On p. 71 below eq. (6.12) in Schwartz book, they assume that 
$$\lim_{t \to \pm\infty}\partial_0 a_p(t)=0.\tag{1}$$ 
But I thought that this is just an assumption. So we have to construct the mathematical description. I found the [Gell-Mann and Low theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_and_Low_theorem). In that theorem,
full Hamiltonian is $$H(t)=H_0+e^{-\epsilon|t|}V(0)\tag{2}$$
and time evolution operator is 
$$U(t,t')=T\exp\bigg[-i\int^{t}_{t'}dt~H(t)\bigg]\tag{3}$$ 
and
$$U_I(t,t')=T\exp\bigg[-i\int^{t}_{t'}dt~e^{-\epsilon|t|}V_I(t)\bigg].\tag{4}$$ 
So I thought that
$$\lim_{t \to \pm\infty}\partial_0 a_p(t)=
iU_I^\dagger(\pm\infty,0)e^{-\epsilon|\pm\infty|}[V(\infty),a_p]U_I(\pm\infty,0).\tag{5}$$ 
and since $t$ is going to infinity, that is 0. by the way, I fell in another problem. If I deal with that time evolution operator as the above, when we use the LSZ formula and $n$-point function, I'll meet the 
$e^{-\epsilon|t|}$. the function will interrupt what delta function about energy is made. what is my fault? please tell me about my incorrect logic. I spend the time a lot due to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Schwartz's treatment of the [LSZ construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LSZ_reduction_formula) is somewhat misleading:

1. Schwartz fails to mention that the Fourier expansion $$ \hat{\phi}(x)~=~\int\! \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_p}}
   \left[\hat{a}_p(t)e^{-ip\cdot x}+\hat{a}^{\dagger}_p(t)e^{ip\cdot x}  \right] \tag{6.7}$$ only applies to a *free* real field.
2. It is not properly explained that $$\sqrt{2\omega_p} \hat{a}_p(t) = i \int \!d^3x~ e^{ipx}\stackrel{\leftrightarrow}{\partial}_0 \hat{\phi}(x)\tag{6.13}$$ is the actual definition of a (time-dependent) asymptotic annihilation operator $\hat{a}_p(t)$. A standard calculation then yields that $$\sqrt{2\omega_p} \partial_0\hat{a}_p(t) = i \int \!d^3x~ e^{ipx}(\Box+m^2) \hat{\phi}(x).$$ This vanishes for free fields where $\hat{a}_p(t)$ belongs to the [Schrödinger picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_picture) and is therefore time-independent.

   OP's main question about $\partial_0\hat{a}_p(\pm \infty)$ therefore directly ties to the validity of the basic adiabatic assumption of the LSZ formalism. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/525800/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/210119/2451) related Phys.SE posts.
3. Below eq. (6.7) it is wrongly asserted that $\hat{a}_p(t)$ belongs to the Heisenberg picture.
4. Below eq. (6.8) it seems that Schwartz assumes that the theory is free for $|t|>T$. In fundamental QFT the interactions are not turned off at asymptotic regions: the Lagrangian does not depend explicitly on spacetime. In particular, $\epsilon=0$ in the Gell-Mann & Low theorem. For any finite $\epsilon>0$, not surprisingly $\partial_0\hat{a}_p(\pm \infty)=0$.

References:

1. M.D. Schwartz, *QFT & the standard model,* 2014;
   p. 22 eq. (2.78);
   p. 23 eq. (2.81);
   p. 71 below eqs. (6.11) & (6.12).